# Create a formula to sum all values number between two ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scwPI.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIMTK.png)I would like to create a excel formula to sum up all values between two ranges when i choose the "cell range" for example between P-2 and P-5 this i can get all the summed values in the in  the "area row"

[image]

Comment: What formula U have tried so far,,,,, just share with us will help us to understand the situation,,,, !

Comment: looks like this can be solved with a combination of INDIRECT, ADDRESS and MATCH

Comment: ...or `SUM(OFFSET(start total cell;0; MATCH();1;MATCH()-MATCH()+1)`

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your help The formula i used SUMIF but it return two values not the summation  see here=SUMIF(E19:Q19,E33:E34,E40:Q40)

Comment: i add additional photo to see the formula

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the formula is helpful.

`=SUM(INDIRECT(CHAR(65+MATCH(INDIRECT("E33"),A19:Q19,0)-1)&40):INDIRECT(CHAR(65+MATCH(INDIRECT("E34"),A19:Q19,0)-1)&40))`.